# `find_or_create_by!` and an `after_initialize` callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback, rails-activerecord

We have something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  after_initialize do |user|
    # stuff1
  end
end

User.find_or_create_by!(email: data[:email]) do |user|
  # stuff2 relying on code from the after_initialize
end
```

Execution of `stuff2` relies on `stuff1` having run, and we're getting a crash indicative of `stuff1` not having run.

This is fixed by using `find_or_initialize_by(..).tap`, but that still leaves a few questions:

1. Which callbacks actually get triggered by `find_or_create_by`? (Ditto for `find_or_initialize_by`)
2. ...Why doesn't `after_initialize` get run?

Comment: Is there a chance that `after_initialize` block doesn't run when `find_or_create` actually founds the object needed? And the opposite - `after_initialize` block runs when `find_or_create` cannot find the object and has to create it?

Comment: Also, are you sure you're persisting whatever happens in `stuff1`? To answer your first question, though, `find_or_create_by` will trigger the `after_find` and/or `after_initialize` callbacks.

Comment: @mmichael We're definitely persisting, since we're not seeing that error elsewhere. I have no idea if it's being overwritten and then `stuff1` gets re-applied. @VAD I think you have the right idea, that the callback chain is different between `find` and `create`.